# How to trigger Kentico 10 Marketing automation?

Tags: triggers, automation, kentico

I'm setting up a new marketing automation in Kentico 10, and want to send some email to cart abandoned contact. How to trigger that marketing automation process ?

I have 2 Kentico servers, they are all Kentico 10, and one is staging, and the other is live.

The difference between them is only one, staging has no web farm, and live has web farms for server load balance.

In staging, I created a new marketing automation process for cart abandonment, and in schedule task, created a schedule task for cart abandonment mark, and checked marketing automation process working.

So I tried to move this automation process to live.

I made marketing automation process in live Kentico server, and added schedule task for cart abandonment mark.

When added item in cart and left, then schedule task for cart abandonment worked normally, and in contact management activity log, new activity for cart abandonment was logged normally.

But that cart marketing automation process was not triggered.

So I tried to start new instance or that process with some contact manually, then that process worked normally.

Now, the only one problem is that marketing automation process is not triggered when cart abandonment occurred.

I expect that marketing automation process is triggered from cart abandonment activity.

Where is my issue ? Or what I missed ?

Comment: What triggers have you configered on the Marketing Automation process? Since it's working when manually adding contact, the trigger seems first point to check!

Comment: Trigger type is "Contact performed an activity", and Activity type is "Shopping cart abandoned"
Of course, in Contact management > Activity Log, "Shopping cart abandoned" type activities are logged normally.

Comment: One more thing, I added MSSQL trigger for activity table insert, about the shopping cart abandoned record insert, copied that contact id into another temporary table, and using another schedule task (1 minute interval), checking that table, and run that marketing automation process programmatically.
But it's temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  {% ActivitySiteID %} macro expression in your design process then you need to apply hotfix 10.0.23 or newer.

Reference - https://docs.kentico.com/k10/on-line-marketing-features/configuring-and-customizing-your-on-line-marketing-features/configuring-marketing-automation/walkthrough-sending-an-automated-reminder-of-an-abandoned-shopping-cart

Comment: Current version is 10.0.41